# From .mexglx to .mex

Tags: matlab, mex

I've been given a Matlab program that uses an external C function. I only have the compiled version of this external function, and the extension is .mexglx . From what I have already red, it seems that this extension is the mex-file version compiled with linux. I run matlab under windows XP, and my problem is that my Matlab is not able to read the .mexglx extension. So my question is: is there any mean to change a file with the .mexglx extension to a .mex? Because for the moment I do not have the source code in C, so I can't recompile it correctly. I precise that my version of Matlab is R2007b if it can help.
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 9):

No there is no way, sorry. You need to get the source code to build it for a different platform.